# Passing posted values from one controller to another in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller

I have two controllers. I find problem in passing posted values from one controller to another. Here is a quick view,

This is the function 1

```
public function setRole(request $request){

this->forward(Path,array(role=>$role));

this->redirect(path of second controller);

}
```

This is the function 2.

```
public function getRole(request $request){

$role = $request->get('role');//when printing this $role, I am able to get the value of $role.

$sql = "select * from table where id=$role"; // I cannot get the value in this qry ,also, i cannot pass the value to a twig file

return render...(filename,array('roleid'=>$role));

}
```

Problem is I could'n access the variable "roleid" in my twig file of second controller. Always it goes empty.

Is there anything i have missed here?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html) :

```
public function indexAction($name) {
$response = $this->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:fancy', array(
    'role'  => $role
));

// ... further modify the response or return it directly. 
// But do not redirect afterwards! 
// Just return the response that the forwarded controller returns

return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this from Googling. From Symfony 3.3 you can use the [session interface](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.html) to pass things from one controller to another.

As the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html) says: To retrieve the session, add the SessionInterface type-hint to your argument and Symfony will provide you with a session.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

public function indexAction(SessionInterface $session)
{
    // store an attribute for reuse during a later user request
    $session->set('foo', 'bar');

    // get the attribute set by another controller in another request
    $foobar = $session->get('foobar');

    // use a default value if the attribute doesn't exist
    $filters = $session->get('filters', array());
}
```